# Получить теги при помощи Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

прошу вашей помощи, каким образом я могу получить теги из такого текста (при помощи Regex)?:

```py
str_ = '<lemma id=1 rev=1>;<l t=ёж>;<g v=NOUN/>;<g v=anim/>;<g v=masc/>;</l>;<f t=ёж>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=nomn/>;</f>;<f t=ежа>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=gent/>;</f>;<f t=ежу>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=datv/>;</f>;<f t=ежа>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=accs/>;</f>;<f t=ежом>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=ablt/>;</f>;<f t=еже>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=loct/>;</f>;<f t=ежи>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=nomn/>;</f>;<f t=ежей>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=gent/>;</f>;<f t=ежам>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=datv/>;</f>;<f t=ежей>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=accs/>;</f>;<f t=ежами>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=ablt/>;</f>;<f t=ежах>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=loct/>;</f>;</lemma>;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\
    <lemma id=2 rev=2>;<l t=ёж>;<g v=NOUN/>;<g v=inan/>;<g v=masc/>;</l>;<f t=ёж>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=nomn/>;</f>;<f t=ежа>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=gent/>;</f>;<f t=ежу>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=datv/>;</f>;<f t=ёж>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=accs/>;</f>;<f t=ежом>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=ablt/>;</f>;<f t=еже>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=loct/>;</f>;<f t=ежи>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=nomn/>;</f>;<f t=ежей>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=gent/>;</f>;<f t=ежам>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=datv/>;</f>;<f t=ежи>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=accs/>;</f>;<f t=ежами>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=ablt/>;</f>;<f t=ежах>;<g v=plur/>;<g v=loct/>;</f>'
```

Необходимо извлечь в массив строк теги l и f полностью, вот так:

```
<l t=ёж>;<g v=NOUN/>;<g v=anim/>;<g v=masc/>;</l>
<f t=ёж>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=nomn/>;</f>
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```py
import re

m = re.findall(r'<[lf][^e].*?>.+?</[lf]>', str_)

for i in m:
    print(i)
```

Объяснение регулярки:

- `<[lf]` - символ `<`, а затем `l` или `f`;
- `[^e]` - любой символ, кроме `e` (чтобы исключить тег `lemma`);
- `.*?>` - любой символ сколько-то раз (в том числе и ноль). `?` означает "ленивый" поиск, т. е. он заканчивается при вхождении символа `>` (иначе этой части шаблона соответствовала бы вся строка до *последнего* символа `>`);
- `.+?` - какой-то текст между открывающимся и закрывающимся тегом. И опять "ленивый" поиск.
- `</[lf]>` - закрывающийся тег `l` или `f`.

Вывод:

```
<l t=ёж>;<g v=NOUN/>;<g v=anim/>;<g v=masc/>;</l>
<f t=ёж>;<g v=sing/>;<g v=nomn/>;</f>
...
```

Comment: Благодарю вас, именно так и хотелось!)